# gspread pulling old version of sheet

Tags: gspread

I've got a bit of an odd problem.  I have a Discord bot that uses gspread to access a Google Sheet - read only, just pulling info.

If I run the bot from my laptop at home, it pulls the correct information.  Once I upload my code to my production server and run it, gspread pulls an older version of the same sheet.  I've confirmed that the sheet ID is the same (since it's coming from a config file) and that the version of Python (3.10) and gspread (5.7.2) are the same.

I expect gspread to pull the latest version of the sheet.  In fact, I believe gspread doesn't even have the ability to access prior versions.  It's almost as if the production server has cached the sheet.  I've restarted the bot but that didn't help.

I've deleted a few rows as a test and those rows continue to show up on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply renaming and then reverting back the filename of the Google Sheet.

I had the same issue - gspread was loading in live versions of files until suddenly it wasn't. Changed the name, and voila! Problem solved, no kernel or computer restart required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I came to your question accidentally because our software development team experienced the same issue.

We had checked deltas on the rows we explicitly ignored in another part of the script. It doesn't seem like a smart error, but it was was it was.

So the library is fine.